# Right Orfeo Toolbox Segmentation input

Tags: landsat, landsat-8, orfeo-toolbox, image-segmentation

[image]

I made this [tutorial](http://wiki.awf.forst.uni-goettingen.de/wiki/index.php/Object-based_classification_(Tutorial)). I used Landsat 8 bands (1-7), which I atmospheric corrected with DOS and converted to 8-bit. After that I layer stacked the pre processed band (1-7), clipped a little part with a polygon shape of the whole image and used it as input for "Exact Large-Scale Mean Shift segmentation step 1".

But after step 4 I just get a very bad segmented shapefile. The tool just segmented a little percentage of the objects in my Landsat 8 clip. Anyone has a idea how to fix this?

Comment: I was going to suggest you to post on otb user mailing list, but I have seen you just posted here.  https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=fr#!topic/otb-users/2C0_wPbdPEw